# how can I export 'Motion - Conversion Specifiers' to use it in a python program? Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python, motion

I'm using motion in a Raspberry Pi and need export the coordinates of the center of the moving object (the %K and %L) because I want to use it in a python program. But I can't even make the on_motion_detected work.

I'm testing it with a python script that runs ok outside motion, but not inside:

```
on_motion_detected python /home/pi/prog/hello.py
```

I already gave permission for the file with: sudo chmod +x /home/pi/prog/hello.py

someone know what's wrong?

Comment: you should specify full path for `python` as well, may easily find it with `which python` (something like `/usr/bin/python` would be the answer)